# ¿Cómo solucionar el error SP BUILDER PAGE Failed en Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla3

Me salió este error cuando instalé el componente:

> SP BUILDER PAGE Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\sitioweb\components\com_sppagebuilder\parser./../helpers/helper.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Como solucionarlo?